# Lots and lots of joins in a Zend Query, hopefully just a slight tweak

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

Apologies for all this code, anyhow Im re-working a query into the Zend query way of working, this is what I have so far:

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get ( "db" );      
    $stmt = $db->query('
    SELECT recipe_pictures.picture_id, recipe_pictures.picture_filename, course.course_name, cuisines.name, recipes.id, recipes.Title, recipes.Method, recipes.author, recipes.SmallDesc, recipes.user_id, recipes.cuisine, recipes.course, recipes.Created_at, recipes.vegetarian, recipes.Acknowledgements, recipes.Time, recipes.Amount, recipes.view_count, recipes.recent_ips, guardian_writers.G_item, guardian_writers.G_type
    FROM recipes
    LEFT JOIN course ON recipes.course = course.course_id
    LEFT JOIN recipe_pictures ON recipes.id = recipe_pictures.recipe_id
    LEFT JOIN cuisines ON recipes.cuisine = cuisines.id
    LEFT JOIN guardian_writers ON recipes.author = guardian_writers.G_author
    WHERE recipes.id = ?', $id);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $recipes = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $recipes;
```

That one above works, trying to get the Zend version properly, my effort is below.

```
    $db = Zend_Registry::get ( "db" );      
    $select = $db->select()
                 ->from(array('r' => 'recipes'))
                 ->join(array('c' => 'course'),
                        'r.course = c.course_id')
                 ->join(array('rp' => 'recipe_pictures'),
                        'r.id = rp.recipe_id')
                 ->join(array('cui' => 'cuisines'),
                        'r.cuisine = cui.id')
                 ->join(array('gw' => 'guardian_writers'),
                        'r.author = gw.G_author')
                 ->where(' id = ? ', $id);

    $recipes = $db->fetchRow($select);

    return $recipes;
```

If anyone can spot an error Id be very grateful, thanks

Comment: Any errors?  Or just no results?

Comment: clever me has mucked up the error controller/or script/ or something, now just a helpful 'an error occured' with no other message!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joinLeft instead of join to produce left joins.

To fetch specific columns from a table, rather than all (*) use this:

```
->from(array('r' => 'recipes'), array('id', 'title', 'method'))
```

or

```
->joinLeft(array('rp' => 'recipe_pictures'),
                    'r.id = rp.recipe_id',
                    array('picture_id', 'picture_filename')
                    )
```

To fetch no columns from a table, pass an empty array as the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` method provides an sql `INNER JOIN`.  If you want to get a `LEFT JOIN` you should use `joinLeft`.